# Laravel Collection. Map one keys to other

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I want to map some keys in Laravel collection to other, that are stored in an array.

I can't "invent" a proper neat and short pipeline for such a transformation.

Here is a simplified example of what I want:

```
$mappedKeys = [
    '1' => 'One',
    '2' => 'Two',
    '3' => 'Three',
    '4' => 'Four',
];

$data = collect([
    '1' => 'I',
    '2' => 'II',
    '3' => 'III',
    '5' => 'V',
]);

$resultCollection = $data->...

/*
 * I want to receive after some manipulations
 *
 * [
 *      'One'   => 'I',
 *      'Two'   => 'II',
 *      'Three' => 'III',
 *      '5'     => 'V',
 * ]
 */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always use the [combine()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-combine) method on the collection:

```
$mappedKeys = [
    '1' => 'One',
    '2' => 'Two',
    '3' => 'Three',
    '4' => 'Four',
];

$data = collect([
    '1' => 'I',
    '2' => 'II',
    '3' => 'III',
    '5' => 'V',
]);

$resultCollection = $data->keyBy(function ($item, $key) use ($mappedKeys) {
    return isset($mappedKeys[$key]) ? $mappedKeys[$key] : $key;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but looks like I have oversimplified. I have an associative array, not a simple one. I have updated an example. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Thank you) I haven't used keyBy before and your solution with it is neat and quite pretty).

Answer (score 1):

Updated Answer

```
$resultCollection = $data->combine($mappedKeys);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have updated the answer, so your solution is outdated, but it was right in the beginning. I'm ready to add +1, if you update it :)

Comment: Sorry, but your solution won't work. I've tried it. I thought you would rewrite your solution in php, so it could be helpful for other people, that don't use collections but have a similar issue.

Comment: `$resultCollection = $mappedKeys->combine($data);`

Comment: @D.R. for a php solution you can just do `array_combine($mappedKeys, $data)`

Comment: this solution is a problem because it will match 'Four' and 'V'